# How do I remove a style element from an inline style using Java regex?

Tags: regex, java-7

I am trying to remove only one property, `height`, and its value, from an inline style. I would like to start with this:

```
<img src="http://hello-world/img/a1.jpg" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; float:right;">
```

And make it like this:

```
<img src="http://hello-world/img/a1.jpg" style="width: 800px; float:right;">
```

I am using Java 7 environment and how can I solve this problem using [Pattern.compile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following regex to detect property height and his value.

```
(<.*?style=.*?)(\s*height.*?;)(.*?>)
```

**Details:**

- <.*?style=.*?: group1 - from tag html to style inline, before property height
- \s*height.*?;: group2 - property height and his value (any unit)
- .*?>: group 3 - rest of the tag html

[Prove](https://regex101.com/r/Kd3rge/1)

Finally, you keep only group 1 and group 3 ("$1$3"). Using [Java Regular Expression Tester](https://extendsclass.com/regex/acbeceb), you test result.

Comment: +1 Thanks alot, it will help me.
I have one more question.

I have tried deleting not only the property `height` but also the property `width` as follows. Do you know a better way than this? 

`(<.*?style\s*=.*?)(\s*[width|height].*?;)(\s*[width|height].*?;)(.*?>)`

Comment: @user2335816 
I suggest my solution. 
`(<.*?style\s*=.*?)(\s*(?:width|height).*?;)(.*?)((?2))(.*?>)`

Details:
 - Please use character ( instead of [
 - `(?2)`: Repeat pattern of group 2

https://regex101.com/r/uL7TAS/3